# I am wondering if this sentence is grammatically correct? Can I use this line in a letter?

Tags: grammar, word-request, difference, grammaticality-in-context, writing

This letter is to inform you that the gender information of Rebecca and Thomas is already updated as female and male in our records.

Answer (score 2):

A potential problem with this sentence (and one that I see very frequently working with people from certain countries) is the use of the word *already*. I assume someone issued a request here to update the gender records, and you completed the request? If that is right, you should not say *is **already** updated*, but instead, *has been updated*.

*Is already updated* means that it was updated before they even made the request. For example, if there were duplicate requests.

Using already can be taken as very slightly offensive because it can imply "you need not have made this request, we were already handling this issue before you said anything."

Comment: Here the customer is asking to update the gender information. But the gender information is already correct in our records. The information was correctly updated in our records when the policy was issued. Now, the customer is making request to update the same information. Hope I am clear.

Comment: Then it didn't need to be updated (corrected), so you could say that the information is _correctly stated in our records_.

Comment: @ShivnathKashyap - Looks like I shouldn't have assumed! Yes, *already* is fine in that case, and my answer is wrong. As Kate said, *updated* could be improved. Perhaps *is already correct* or even *is already up to date*. These are all pretty minor issues though -- your original is perfectly grammatical.